# PHP Curl: detect "unable to get local issuer certificate" error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

Sometimes my PHP Curl users don't have the trusted certs installed.

When my php app attempts to use curl to contact an HTTPS server ("curl out"), the attempt fails.

If I set PHP Curl to verbose mode, I can see the error message

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

**But how can I detect that problem from within my code?**

Curl is returning 0 for both the `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` and `CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT` values.

I want to programmatically detect this situation so I can tell the admin what to do.

Comment: Are we talking about local users trying to CURL out or you trying to CURL in?

Comment: Curl out. I've updated the Q. Thank you.

Comment: Next question: are these self signed certificates you're dealing with or are they just signed with a CA that is not installed?

Comment: The server is a regular commercial server with a cert that traces to Verisign. I know how to fix the problem (install/configure trusted CA certs from the curl website or elsewhere). What I'm trying to figure out is how can I automatically tell the administrators that their PHP installation is not configured with the trusted CA list?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
public function get($url){
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     if(curl_errno($ch)){
         throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
     }
     return $result;
}
try{
     $object->get('http://example.com');
} catch(Exception $e){
     //do something with the exception you caught
}
```